# How to make ipython use python 3.7 instead of 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

On a MacbookAir Mojave I have ipython installed, but when I run it it always used python 3.6.9 instead of python 3.7.

How to change/update ipython so it used python 3.7 instead?

I tried to run

```
sudo pip3 install ipython
```

which did install something, but it still uses only python 3.6.9.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use

```
ipython3
```

instead to use python 3.7 (...?).